# My service function does not send HTTP request

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework

I am making a mobile app using Ionic and Angular i have a function in my angular service that sends a post request to the server

the problem i have is that request is never sent just nothing happens when i use the request in the URL it works but not in my app

```
   marquerDevoirLu(devoir_id){
   console.log(devoir_id);
   let etudiant_id = this.loginService.importantdata['etudiant_id'];
   console.log(etudiant_id);
   let utilisateur_id = this.loginService.importantdata['utilisateur_id'];
   console.log(utilisateur_id);
   console.log(`${this.baseUrl}?func=marquerDevoirLu`)
   return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}?func=marquerDevoirLu`,{etudiant_id, devoir_id, utilisateur_id}).pipe(map(user => {
     console.log(user['result']);
     if(user['result'] == 'success'){
       console.log('success');
   
     }

     else{
       console.log('echec');

     }
    
 }));
 }
```

Comment: Where do you make the subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you make a subscription, if you do map function is returning a value so return something.
If you only want to use the data to log, use tap or move the function to the subscription.

`return this.http.post(${this.baseUrl}?func=marquerDevoirLu,{etudiant_id, devoir_id, utilisateur_id}).pipe(tap(user) => {user['result']?console.log('success'):console.log('echec')}).subscribe((value)=>{})`